# Exclude column from WebAPI IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to exclude a column from my WebAPI's IQueryable function? e.g. How would I exclude the property "FirstName" from my people entity:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Contact> GetPeople()
{
    return _contextProvider.Context.People;
}
```

pseudocoded:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Contact> GetPeople()
{
    return _contextProvider.Context.People.ExcludeColumn("FirstName");
}
```

Comment: If it's in another assembly you could also make it `internal` in the modelcontainer.

Comment: Google for [JsonIgnore]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Project results manually to `Contact` entity, and do not provide data for `FirstName` column:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Contact> GetPeople()
{
    return from p in _contextProvider.Context.People
           select new Contact {
               Id = p.Id,
               LastName = p.LastName
           };
}
```

BTW I'd create some other specific DTO object which don't have `FirstName` property.

Comment: keep in mind not all linq providers will be able to translate queries against the projected entities into queries against the root entity. ef objectcontext didnt seem to tho dbcontext does.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to decorate the column with `Runtime.Serialization.IgnoreDataMember` like this.

```
[Runtime.Serialization.IgnoreDataMember]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```